# Получение информации о всех использованных USB устройствах

Tags: linux, администрирование

Как можно на Linux получить информацию о всех USB устройствах, которые когда бы то нибудь подключались в данному ПК? И вообще такого рода логирование ведётся?

Comment: угу. http://askubuntu.com/questions/408069/log-usb-connect-and-disconnect-in-ubuntu-13-x